# Is it possible to set multiple conditions for a loop?

Tags: c++, loops, do-while

Is it possible to set multiple conditions for a loop? In this case, specifically a do...while loop. I'm trying to go back over a bunch of old content that I never even practiced because I naively believed reading over example code was good enough so that I can get a bit of experience, but nothing I'm trying is working. It either ends up looping indefinitely, or it'll only consider one condition and keep looping with the other. *Thank you in advance for the help.*

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int input;
    cout<<"What species do you belong to?"<<endl;
    cout<<"1 - Human\n2 - Other\n"<<endl;
    do
    {
        cin>>input;
        switch(input)
        {
        case 1:
            {
                cout<<"OK"<<endl;
                break;
            }
        case 2:
            {
                cout<<"what"<<endl;
                break;
            }
        default:
            {
                cout<<"INVALID INPUT\n"<<endl;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    while(input!=1||input!=2);
}
```

Comment: `input!=1||input!=2` is always true.

Comment: Input is *always* going to be different from 1 or different from 2. Let's see: if it's 0, then it's both. If it's 1, then it's different from 2. And if it's 2, then it's different from 1. You probably wanted `&&`, and not `||`.

Comment: `input != 1 && input != 2`

Comment: Also, to be "defensive", consider initializing your `int input = 0;`.

Comment: Well that fixed it.. I feel dumb now haha, I need to brush up on conditions too I suppose - thanks a lot, that was a big help. Definitely felt good fixing that within seconds of posting the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A key concept to keep in mind is that the input variable can only have one value at at time. In the case of your code, it appears you want to:

- continue the loop if the value of `input` is not 1, and
- continue the loop if the value of `input` is not 2,
- and in any other case, terminate the loop

To continue looping for the two cases above, you can combine logical operators to achieve this.

Specifically, you can use the logical operators `!=` and `&&` to say:

> continue looping when input is neither 1 or 2

Which is the same as saying:

> continue looping when input is not 1 and is not 2

This can be achieve by updating the loop condition in your code as follows:

```
do {
    cin>>input;
    switch(input)
    {
    case 1:
        {
            cout<<"OK"<<endl;
            break;
        }
    case 2:
        {
            cout<<"what"<<endl;
            break;
        }
    default:
        {
            cout<<"INVALID INPUT\n"<<endl;
            break;
        }
    }

// Only allow the loop to continue if input is something other than 1 
// or 2, ie not 1 and not 2
} while(input!=1 && input!=2);
```

Comment: I have to say, I'm already liking this community. Thank you, got my question answered as soon as I put it up and with a full explanation of how and why I messed up. Once again, thank you for the help, everybody here just made my day

Comment: You're more than welcome, please consider answering the question if you found it helpful :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can make a loop condition with whatever expression evaluates to `true/false`, no hard limit on how many comparisons you can put there.

However, your code is checking the same variable for two different values with an 'or' gate that will always return true, since a variable can only hold one value. If `input` is `1` it cannot be `2`, if it's `2` it cannot be `1`, so your expression will always be `true` and this is an infinite loop.

Perhaps you wanted to use `&&` ('and' gate) instead of `||`.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need here is and statement '&&' instead of or '| |'. When you enter 1 for example,  condition input != 2 is True, and therefore the loop continues. With and statement input != 1 && input != 2, loop will cancel once input is either 1 or 2. But I am confused whats the point of loop if you do not want it to iterate indefinately?

Comment: I just wanted to test some knowledge I learned a few years back in a semi-worthless script that I'd be deleting soon after anyways - failed my own test haha. Thank you though, definitely is the answer I was looking for